# Using Arcpy to assign layer scale range

Tags: arcpy

Does anyone know if there is an Arcpy function to set a scale range?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`layer.minScale` and `layer.maxScale`.

From the [ArcGIS Help](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#P_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878) for the `Layer` class:

> maxScale (Read and Write) - Provides the ability to set or get the
>   layer's maximum scale threshold (Double)
>
> minScale (Read and Write) - Provides the ability to set or get the layer's minimum scale threshold
>   (Double)